# Google Script Apps Editor - Calculating Days difference

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I`m trying to calculate days difference between two dates

It will be, NOW() - the date listed in the data
In the below example, (2019-03-08 - 2018-10-31) = 128 days for the first row

```
Dates      Days Regions
2018-10-31  128 Alberta
2018-10-31  128 Alberta
2018-11-8   120 Alberta
2018-11-18  110 Alberta
```

the dataset looks like the above

The thing is, I`m trying to get that value calculated whenever user updates that "Dates" column.

Below is the code I tried

```
function dategenerator() {
  const numberofHeaderRows=1
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange("A:A")
  var legitrange = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var rangeValuesInclHeaders = range.getValues()
  var rangeValuesExclHeaders = rangeValuesInclHeaders.slice(numberofHeaderRows)
  var dates=rangeValuesExclHeaders.map(function(row){return row[0]})

  for (var rowNumber=numberofHeaderRows;rowNumber<rangeValuesInclHeaders.length;rowNumber++){
    var row = rangeValuesInclHeaders[rowNumber]
    if (row[0]!==""){

    var dates = new Date(row[0])
    var datesnew = new Date()
    var t1 = datesnew.getTime()
    var t2 = dates.getTime()
    var diffInDays = Math.floor((t1 - t2)/(1000*60*60*24))
      Logger.log(diffInDays)
      spreadsheet.getRange(1,2,legitrange.length,1).setValue(diffInDays);
    }
  }
}
```

I see the right values under "diffInDays" 
However, it is only pulling the last value, like below...

```
Dates      Days Regions
2018-10-31  110 Alberta
2018-10-31  110 Alberta
2018-11-8   110 Alberta
2018-11-18  110 Alberta
```

How do we get this work properly so that it can append the calculated value to the right dates row?

Comment: What's wrong with `=DATEDIF`?

Comment: It`s just that I need this to be run on the back-end so that users can easily go and update cells - they get super confused when formulas are embedded..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Calculate Days whenever Column one changes

```
function diffInDays(Start,End)
{
  if(Start && End)
  {
    var second=1000;
    var minute=60*second;
    var hour=minute*60;
    var day=hour*24;
    var t1=new Date(Start).valueOf();
    var t2=new Date(End).valueOf();
    var d=t2-t1;
    var days=Math.floor(d/day);
    return days;
  }
  else
  {
    throw('Invalid Inputs');
  }
}

function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='SheetName'){return;}//add sheetName
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value){
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(diffInDays(e.value,new Date());
  }
}
```

Format column one to be Datetime

Comment: So when I run this, I get this error TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 26,

Comment: I've edited  just recently so you may want to get a fresh copy and you said `The thing is, I'm trying to get that value calculated whenever user updates that "Dates" column.` in order to do that I'm using onEdit(e) trigger.  And you can't run that from the Script Editor or more precisely you can't run that without an event object.

Comment: ohh I see, and apologies for the confusion - and it is working as intended! - is it possible to do the same for the existing dates as well? - basically like the code I wrote above? and then combine this with onEdit..?

Comment: Probably.  Keep in mind that this code must complete in 30 seconds so keep it short and to the point.